# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: javafx-8

Student fxml controller

I have a similar code for teacher that populate database to table view and it works but dont know why am having error in this one the last error points to
    `teacherTable.setItems(ban);`
pls what do i do

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at schoolmanagement.Student.StudentZoneController.load(StudentZoneController.java:65)
    ... 70 more
```

```java
package schoolmanagement.Student;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;


import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class StudentZoneController {
 Connection con;
 PreparedStatement p;
 String rowid,fname,lname,age,sex,cl;
 ResultSet set;
 Alert popup;




    @FXML
     private TableView<usera> teacherTable;


    @FXML
    private TableColumn<usera, String> ROWID;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<usera, String> FIRSTNAME;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<usera, String> LASTNAME;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<usera, String> AGE;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<usera, String> SEX;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<usera, String> CLASS;



@FXML
private void load ()
{


     ObservableList<usera> ban =FXCollections.observableArrayList( );

    teacherTable.setItems(ban);

}

@FXML
private void initialize()
{
    ROWID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<usera,String>("rowid"));
    FIRSTNAME.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<usera,String>("firstname"));
    LASTNAME.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<usera,String>("lastname"));
    AGE.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<usera,String>("age"));
    SEX.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<usera,String>("sex"));
    CLASS.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<usera,String>("primary"));

}

@FXML
private TextField t1;

@FXML
private TextField t2;

@FXML
private TextField t3;

@FXML
private DatePicker dob;


@FXML
private TextField t4;

@FXML
private TextField t5;

@FXML
private TextField t6;

@FXML
private TextField t7;

@FXML
private TextField t8;

@FXML
private TextField t9;

@FXML
private TextField t10;

@FXML
private TextField t11;

@FXML
private TextField t12;

@FXML
private TextField t13;










@FXML
private void showAge()
{
   Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
   int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   int birth = (dob.getValue().getYear());
   int age = year-birth;
   t4.setText(Integer.toString(age) + "years old");



}





    @FXML
    private void addNewUser() throws SQLException
    {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con =(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school?"+"user=root&password =");
             p = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement)con.prepareStatement("insert into students values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
             p.setString(1, t1.getText());
             p.setString(2, t2.getText());
             p.setString(3, t3.getText());
             p.setString(4, t4.getText());
             p.setString(5, t5.getText());
             p.setString(6, t6.getText());

             popup = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
             popup.setTitle("INFORMATION DIALOG");
             popup.setHeaderText(null);
             popup.setContentText("user created");
             popup.showAndWait();

             p.executeUpdate();
             p.close();
             clearFields();
        }

        catch(Exception eb)
        {

        }



    }



    @FXML
    private void deleteStudent()
    {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con =(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school?"+"user=root&password =");
             p = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement)con.prepareStatement("delete from students where FIRSTNAME = ? || LASTNAME = ?");
             p.setString(1, t2.getText());
             p.setString(2, t3.getText());

             popup = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
             popup.setTitle("INFORMATION DIALOG");
             popup.setHeaderText(null);
             popup.setContentText("STUDENT DELETED");
             popup.showAndWait();
             refreshDelete();

             p.executeUpdate();
        }

        catch(Exception l)
        {
             popup = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
             popup.setTitle("INFORMATION DIALOG");
             popup.setHeaderText(null);
             popup.setContentText(l.getMessage());
             popup.showAndWait();


        }


    }


    private void clearFields()
    {
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");
        t3.setText("");
        t4.setText("");
        t5.setText("");
        t6.setText("");
        dob.setValue(null);



    }

    @FXML
    private void resetFields()
    {
        t9.clear();
        t10.clear();
        t11.clear();
        t12.clear();
        t13.clear();
    }
    private void refreshDelete()
    {

        t2.clear();
        t3.clear();
    }



}
```

Comment: You have a npo at line 65. Has ban a value in the load method?

Comment: Presumably `teacherTable` is null. Check the `fx:id` is set correctly in the FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

I found that something much like this happens when I am using scenebuilder with Javafx.
If you go to scenebuilder after building your controller in a MVC build, then you add a new Javafxml event action in the scenebuilder, but you don't update the controller to deal with the new event, it will pop up something similar to this.
You could try checking to make sure every event in the .fxml class is present in the java controller class for that scene.